# Get return value of (static) function with no parameters C++

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I have the following function:

```
content::mojom::CreateViewParamsPtr content::mojom::CreateViewParams::New() {
  CreateViewParamsPtr rv;
  mojo::internal::StructHelper<CreateViewParams>::Initialize(&rv);
  return rv;
}
```

How can I get the return value if the function is called in my Main function as follows or at least show that the return value exists?

```
int PatrickMainChrome(int argc, const char** argv)  {

content::mojom::CreateViewParams::New();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Like you would when calling any other function returning a value, you create a variable and assign the result to it?

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
content::mojom::CreateViewParamsPtr myViewPtr = content::mojom::CreateViewParams::New();
//or shorter
auto myViewPtr = content::mojom::CreateViewParams::New();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the return value if the function is called in my Main function

```
auto rv = content::mojom::CreateViewParams::New();
```